# rails content_for rendering content twice

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I use fields_for as so:

```
<%= f.fields_for :task_comments, @task_category.task_comments do |task_comment_builder| %>
  <%= render 'field', f: task_comment_builder %>
<% end %>
```

My fields partial contains the following:

```
<% content_for :dynamic_field do %>
  <%= f.text_field :comment %>
<% end %>

<%= render 'shared/dynamic_field' %>
```

dynamic_field partial contains this:

```
<div class="field-border">
  <%= yield :dynamic_field %>
</div>
```

What happens is if there are 3 task comments, instead of displaying the comment field once for each task_comment, it displays the comment field twice for each task_comment.

What might I be doing wrong?

Comment: I would try inspecting `@task_category.task_comments` to see if it contains what you expect it to. Also, I'm not entirely sure what the deal with the partials is, there's no need to nest two partials like that, you might as well just put `<div class="field-border"><%= f.text_field :comment %></div>` in the first partial.

Comment: @Karl, the example above is oversimplified. There will be a lot of markup in the dynamic_field partial that I want to reuse. Hence I want to be able to yield different content from it.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using content_for, I decided to use render layout, which does the job:

```
<%= f.fields_for :task_comments, @task_category.task_comments do |task_comment_builder| %>
  <%= dynamic_fields task_comment_builder do |f| %>
    <%= render 'field', f:f %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>

  # application_helper.rb
  def dynamic_fields(f, options = {}, &block)
    options[:id] ||= "#{f.object.class.name.underscore}_#{f.object.object_id}"
    render layout: "shared/dynamic_fields", locals: {f: f, options: options}, &block
  end

# shared/_dynamic_fields.html.erb
<div class="field-border">
  <%= link_to(raw('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i>'), '#', class: 'btn btn-danger remove-field', style: "float: right;") %>
  <div style="clear: both; padding-top: 3px;">
    <%= yield f %>
  </div>
</div>
```